Solving a System of Equations Involving Complex Variables and Their Magnitudes
I’m trying solving a system of equations with two complex variables,  x  and  y . The equations are given by:
$$  x + y = c_1  \\  |x| + |y| = r 
$$
where  $c_1$  is a given complex number and r is a given real number.
I’m trying to find the complex solutions for  x  and  y  without assuming they are purely real. The challenge arises because the variables have both real and imaginary parts, which seems to effectively double the number of variables in the system. Thus we end up with two equations for four variables. Is that correct? My research problem includes a system of 28 such equations, so understanding how to solve this toy example will help me extend it to the full system. My main question is simply how to solve such a system? Is analytical solution possible? What happens to the idea that if we have the number of variables equaling the number of equations we have a unique solution given the equations are 'nice'?
Any help or pointers towards relevant methods and theories would be greatly appreciated, as would examples of similar problems and their solutions.

Just consider $x+y=c_1$.  It's true that if you expand it into real and imaginary parts, you'll have four unknown real variables, but you won't have one equation: you'll have two.

@copper.hat Oh yes, my bad...I will edit it

@BrianMoehring Right, that makes sense. But nonetheless, we will have three equations in total. Because first one decomposes into two but the second one can't be decomposed into two, so total three. Is that correct? If so, how do we solve for four variables using these three given equations?

Don't get all the downvotes.

You can start by eliminating $y = c_1 - x$.  The remaining equation is
$$ |x| + |c_1 - x| = r$$
Think of this geometrically in the complex plane.  $|x| = s$ says $x$ is on the circle of radius $s$ centred at $0$.  And $|c_1 - x| = r - s$ (if $r > s$) says $x$ is on the circle of radius $r - s$ centred at $c_1$.
If $|c_1| > r$, this is impossible because the triangle inequality gives $$|c_1| = |x + c_1 - x| \le |x| + |c_1 - x| = r$$  But if $|c_1| \le r$, take any $s$ with $$ \frac{r - |c_1|}{2} \le  s \le \frac{r+|c_1|}{2}$$
and the points where the circles intersect will be solutions.
